# Why is error coming up for TinyMce blog editor?

Tags: php, javascript, html, editor, blogs

I have installed the TinyMce blog editor to my site. When the compose blog page loads a I get a pop up that has the yield sign and says "Developer Key Validation Failed" Anyone know what this is?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cysticlife.org/javascripts/jquery/jquery.corners.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/system/config.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script src="http://gdata-javascript-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/blogger/blog_this/blog_this.js"></script>
<div id="blog_this"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a Google Data API error message; if so it's unrelated to TinyMCE. Are you using any Google data in the same page? If so, check your API key.

Comment: I have google analytics running on the site but not on this page. Also when that error message pops up, a 30 or so pixel white bar drops down from the top of my page and has a login button, which then takes me to Google accounts. How do I check the API key? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what that bar is—can you edit your question and post all the `<script>` tags in that page please (put them at the bottom)? Then I can see exactly what you are including.

Comment: I see the problem. This line: `<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>` - you need to replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with an api key for your domain. Go here to get your key: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/signup.html

Comment: I installed the API key, the pop up warning is now gone but no Blog editor and the white bar with the 'login' button is still there. What's going on? Thanks so much for your help by the way!

Comment: Also, I don't think I chose the write download for the blog editor, cause I went and logged in via the login button, and then this very broken blog form came out of the top of my page, looked like it was attached to that google account. pretty confused right now. LOL